# AdMob - InterstitialAd not showing on real device

Tags: android, admob

My banner adview showing correctly on real device and emulator. But interstilialad  now showing real device although it showing correctly on emulator.
Every thing is okey for me. But i didn't understand why not showing.

> EzFullScreenAds.class

```
public class EzFullScreenAds {     

InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
Context context;

    public EzFullScreenAds(Context context) {           //constructor
    this.context = context;

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(context.getString(R.string.adv_fullscreen));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) mInterstitialAd.show();
          }
      });
   }

}
```

> That is usage it.

```
new EzFullScreenAds(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 2):

May be because it cannot fill.

To show test ad on real device you must add real test device ID. `AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR` *only* work on emulator.

> The Mobile Ads SDK uses the tag "Ads" when writing to logcat. You can
>   filter for that tag in Android Studio's logcat viewer, which makes it
>   easier to find your device's ID.

More information here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/targeting#adrequest

Comment: It's okay. I'm already seeing test ads. My problem is that i cant see real ads on my phone.

Comment: Do you create ad for the first time? Without some considerable of traffic it may take a while to show up may be hours or days I can't remember.

Comment: I'm waiting. I tried with two phone.(Asus zenfone2 and zenfone 6) But didnt fix. I will try tomorrow with samsung or different phone.

Comment: I don't think it is the issue with the phone. It is just Ad network need to learn about your traffic before it can send real ad. Generally, if you able to show test ad the real ad will working fine. But it always feel better if you see real ad, I know :)

Comment: Yeap, i think like yours. I believe that i will see real ad! And if i be a good child, maybe i can see smurfs. :)

Answer (score 1):

You did not add your device number as a test device. 
The way you this is:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) // All emulators
    .addTestDevice("A1124HIDFBIUBQWASFDSAFD")    // This is what is missing
    .build();
```

The way how you can find your number is once you have the admob SDK installed(as you already have) You run the emulater and inside the log (that you can find in your working enviroment) press "ctrl + f" and search for "device".

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for helps. İ'm seeing test ads. İt's okay, no problem there. İ didn't see real ads on my phone.

Comment: Thats good! regarding the test adds they ask not to use real ads untill your app is live. The way to see real ads is to put your unique ID that the AdMob gave you. Don't forget to erase your device from the test ads or else you will continue to get test ads :-)